# Is this way of calling object supposed to be bad practice when considering loading speed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My way

**controller pattern 1**  (note: Here, it's calling all users!!)

```
@users = User.confirmed.joins(:profile)
```

**view pattern 1**  (note: Here, it only shows first 10 users but it show the number of all users!!)

```
<%= "ALL ("+ @users.count.to_s + " users)" %>

<% @users.limit(10).each do |users| %>
    <%= render 'users/user', :user => users %>
<% end %>
```

Should it be just like this below if I'm considering page loading speed?
Or it won't be changed?

**controller pattern 2**  (note: I added `limit(10)`, and `@users_count` to count all users)

```
@users = User.confirmed.joins(:profile).limit(10)
@users_count = User.confirmed.joins(:profile).count
```

**view pattern 2**  (note: I took it off `limit(10)` and use `@users_count` for count)

```
<%= "ALL ("+ @users_count.to_s + " users)" %>

<% @users.each do |users| %>
    <%= render 'users/user', :user => users %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Aren't you trying to make pagination in here?

Comment: @MichałSzyndel No pagination here:) Just 10 users to show

Comment: Ok, but why do you join profile in here? I think there's no point in doing join if you have no conditions on joined table? You might want to use incudes instead to have less queries performed.

Comment: @MichałSzyndel ahh, just ignore that please:) could you tell me which pattern of them should be more suitable in this case?

Comment: here you are http://stackoverflow.com/a/17063382/2422778

Comment: @MichałSzyndel yes you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two options are exactly the same. Neither of them loads all the `User`s because you're just chaining scopes. The query is only run when you call .each in the view, at which point you've applied the `.limit(10)` anyway. I'd go with the first option because the code is cleaner.

`@users.count` does one query to get the count, it doesn't instantiate any `User` objects.
`@users.limit(10).each ...` does one query (actually two because you've used `includes`) with a limit, so it will instantiate 10 objects plus your includes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer:) So you prefer Pattern 1 because it looks cleaner? Are you sure that the speed of them are the same?

Comment: I do. I'm 95% sure, but why don't you try it and look at the logs. I answered this question about 6 minutes before anyone else but the guy who writes the same answer gets the tick :\ there's no justice on SO! heh..

Answer (score 2):

If you have lazy loading disabled, then the second approach would be faster because Rails doesn't need to fetch all records from the database. You should really fetch only the records you need when performing queries.

If you have lazy loading enabled (by default), then it is the same, because the data is fetched when it is needed, so the effect will be the same. You can also put two variables in controller and write the same query as you did in the view and the data will be fetched only if and when it is needed.

```
@users = User.confirmed.joins(:profile)
@users_count = @users.count
@users = @users.limit(10)
```

You can check sql generated by the app in your rails console and then decide.

Also, if you are using profile in user.html.erb, consider using includes instead of join. Join can cause n+1 problem if you need associated records. If you don't, you do not want to fetch records you don't need. You can read more about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), in 12 Eager Loading Associations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer:) So you also think my 2 patterns shows the same speed?

Comment: Yes. You can execute this and see the log from rails server (in development environment). It shows you which SQL code is generated, and it is exactly the same :)

Comment: You are welcome :) I recommend you to read about eager loading, it can cause major bottleneck if joins and includes are not used properly.

Answer (score 1):

you can try `@users.find_in_batches`

Please take a look
[Find in batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches)

Please let me know

If you  want speed loading

I can suggest you `memcache` [Memcache](https://github.com/ninjudd/memcache)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But here, I want to know which of my 2 options are faster:) Could you give me an advice on that?

Comment: both are same but as limit given so that will be faster but why you give limit use find_in_batches Thanks let me know if any other help

Comment: if I'm using find_in_batch, what would be the advantage? Could you please show me how to use find_in_batch in my case?